# Output waveform of VCO

Tags: vco

[image: vco]

This is a differential VCO which produces a sine waveform at the output taken across the drains of the MOSFETs. How should I interpret the drain current waveform at that point? Will it be a proper sine wave like the voltage or somewhat distorted?

Comment: Get a free sim tool and simulate it.

Comment: how  RdsOn changes with X(f) defines the Q and thus linearity from f/delta f so wide band is distorted, narrow band can be sine